# Encoding error for question title in chat transcript

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

As can be seen in [this link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1992606#1992606), the chat transcript messes up `'` in a question title. (I think I have seen this happen with other characters, too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was already fixed a few days ago, but oneboxes are rendered when they're first posted and that one was made when the bug still existed. If you [post that link again](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2619404#2619404) it will come out right

Comment: Indeed! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2024558#2024558 Thanks!